# Need to create a json string from Jbuilder in rails Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, helper, jbuilder

I need to create a complex json from my Rails helper

I tried to use Jbuilder for that.
I tried a code from a xxxx.json.jbuilder and it is working great.

```
json.array! @demandes.includes(....) do |demande| 
  json.id demande.id
  json.title demande.title
  .....
end
```

from my_app_url/xxxx.json, the object is well generated.

But I want to generate the object from a Rails Helper and assigne it to a variable.
It's possible?
If yes, how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Rendering.html#method-i-render_to_string

Comment: Thanks Max, that help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with:

`ApplicationController.render(template: 'demandes/index', assigns: { demandes: @demandes })`

(Substitute with your template name)

Comment: Thank you! Awesome!!